# How to use an array as a variable in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have this .sql script:

```
DO $$
  DECLARE 
    user_list integer[] = (select user_id from user where state = 'ACTIVE');
BEGIN
    CREATE CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW accounts_with_active_users AS
    select * from accounts where user_account IN (user_list);
    ...

    CREATE CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW accounts_without_active_users AS
    select * from accounts where user_account NOT IN (user_list);
    ...
END $$;
```

However I always have this error:

```
ERROR: cannot cast type integer to integer[]
```

Also I have tried with the word `array` before with the same result:

```
user_list integer[] = array(...)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to assign a row set to an array. You can use `array_agg()` instead.

```sql
user_list integer[] = (select array_agg(user_id) from users where state = 'ACTIVE');
```

That being said this IMHO doesn't really help you with creating your materialized views. Just inline your select

```sql
CREATE CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW accounts_with_active_users AS
    SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_account IN (
        SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE state = 'ACTIVE'
    );
```

or create an `active_users` view

```sql
CREATE VIEW active_users AS SELECT * FROM users WHERE state = 'ACTIVE';
```

and use it instead

```sql
CREATE CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW accounts_with_active_users AS
    SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_account IN (
        SELECT user_id FROM active_users;
    );
```

Comment: You might get a better plan with `WHERE [NOT] EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE users.user_id = accounts.user_account AND user.state = 'ACTIVE')`. Try both and see what's better.