# Store Results of Dynamic Query Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, dynamicquery

I currently have a function:

```
Create Or Replace Function pvt()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS '
declare
    sqlColumn varchar;
    qr varchar;
    columnlist varchar;
Begin
sqlColumn= ''select distinct D.sys_cat from (select Row_Number() Over (Partition By Project,Date_ Order By System_) as sys_cat From your_table) D order by D.sys_cat;'';
qr=''prepare pvtstmt as Select D.Project,D.Date_,'';

For columnlist In EXECUTE sqlColumn  
   Loop
      qr=qr || ''
      Max(Case When sys_cat=''|| chr(39) || columnlist || chr(39) ||'' Then System_ ||'' ||chr(39)||''-''||chr(39)||''|| Result_ Else '' ||chr(39)||chr(39)||'' End) As System'' ||  columnlist ||  '' , '';
   END LOOP;
   
   qr=substr(qr, 0, length(qr) - 1);
   qr=qr || ''From 
   (select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Project,Date_ Order By System_) as sys_cat From your_table) D Where D.Project='' || chr(39) || ''Proj1'' || chr(39) || ''Group By D.Project,D.Date_ Order By D.Project,D.Date_'';
   
Deallocate All;
EXECUTE qr;
End;
'
```

I run these two commands which produces a table

```
Select pvt();
Execute pvtstmt
```

I am wondering if there is any way to store the results of this table temporarily, so I can query it further. Thank you!

Comment: @nbk, hey thanks for the reply! could you perhaps clarify which select you are referring to and how to insert the results, I tried a few different functions but I kept getting errors. Thank you!

Comment: i am sorry posgres doesn't allow create table in the statement, the documentation wasn't that clear on that point over statements

Comment: okay no worries, if I wanted to create an "Overall" column where it stores "PASS" if all of the Systems contain "PASS" and "FAIL" if one or more of the Systems contains "FAIL", do you know how I could do that within this query?

Comment: You can save result as variable, but remember the rule is the result from select query MUST have one column and one row only. So make sure you serialize it as array value or JSON value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272446/how-to-use-an-array-as-a-variable-in-postgres

Comment: Make your life and embrace [Dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) per [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) and [plpgsql quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-development-tips.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-TIPS).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver could you clarify how I could do that? I haven't used that format before. My goal is to just store the result of the Execute query somehow as a table so I can add more columns and such. Thank you!

Comment: The links I posted show how to do this. Using dollar quoting will reduce the amount of quote escaping you have to do and will make your code easier to write and follow.

Comment: You could do `RETURN QUERY/TABLE` per here [Declare parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS) and then do `select * from pvt()` or `create temp table pvt_tmp as select * from pvt()`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that creates a table for the pvt() function call, but my desired table is returned after Executing pvtstmt